# ZF3 erro 404 para um nome específico de módulo

Tags: php, zend, zend-framework-3

Tenho uma **rota** no meu site que é vinculada à um **módulo** chamado **Carrinho**, mas apesar de parecer estar tudo conforme o tutorial e documentação do zend, essa rota não é encontrada e sempre da `erro 404`.

Após várias tentativas de diferentes modificações para ver se o código funcionava, modifiquei então o nome do **módulo** para **Carrinho2**, e também os `namespaces` dos seus respectivos arquivos (Controladores, Entidades, Modelos...). Por incrível que pareça, a rota passou a ser encontrada, mudando apenas o nome do módulo. Mas é realmente necessário que o nome do módulo seja Carrinho.

Dei um `Find` no projeto para ver se essa palavra **Carrinho** estava em algum arquivo de configuração que possa comprometer o módulo com esse nome e não encontrei nada.

Alguém aí já passou por isso e/ou tem uma ideia do que possa ser?

**modules/Carrinho/config/module.config.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Carrinho;

use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'carrinho' => array(
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/carrinho[/:action][/:produto][/:dados]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action'   => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'produto'   => '[a-zA-Z0-9_,]*',
                        'dados' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_=]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => Controller\CarrinhoController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'carrinho' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),

    'asset_manager' => array( 
        'resolver_configs' => array( 
            'paths' => array( 
                __DIR__ . '/../asset', 
            ), 
        ),
     ),
);
```

**module/Carrinho/src/Module.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Carrinho;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    const VERSION = '3.0.3-dev';

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories' => [
                Controller\CarrinhoController::class => function($container) {
                    return new Controller\CarrinhoController($container);
                },
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Esses são os códigos que ao serem mudados o `namespace` e o nome da pasta, passam a funcionar.

**config/modules.config.php:**

```
<?php
return [
    'Zend\Log',
    'Zend\Mvc\Console',
    'Zend\Mvc\I18n',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\FilePrg',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\FlashMessenger',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\Identity',
    'Zend\Mvc\Plugin\Prg',
    'Zend\Navigation',
    'Zend\Serializer',
    'Zend\ServiceManager\Di',
    'Zend\Paginator',
    'Zend\Cache',
    'Zend\Session',
    'Zend\Mail',
    'Zend\Form',
    'Zend\InputFilter',
    'Zend\Filter',
    'Zend\Hydrator',
    'Zend\I18n',
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Db',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'AwsModule',
    'AssetManager',
    'Neilime\MobileDetect',
    'Carrinho',
    'Catalogo',
    'Cliente',
    'Geral',
    'Localidade',
    'Sitemap',
    //'Carrinho2',
];
```

Comment: A pessoa entra no post, nunca deve ter usado zend, e da downvote só porque não entendeu a pergunta, sem nem ao menos dizer qual o problema que ela viu na pergunta para isto... Essa comunidade está de parabéns.

Comment: Não chegou a ver se é cache? Eu uso zend 1 e ele cacheia as rotas então ele por ter cacheado quando estava dando erro e mesmo após ter sido corrigido o erro persistir.

Comment: Já verifiquei sim @fajuchem, no ambiente de desenvolvimento não está cacheando as rotas. =/

Comment: Mostra o código de onde tu monta as rotas e onde tu faz os vinculos. Sem o código fica dificil ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que no arquivo **config/modules.config.php**, a ordem dos módulos no array de `namespaces` do projeto interfere de alguma forma no `ZF3` de uma maneira que não interferia no `ZF2`. Reparei que quando eu mudava pra **Carrinho2**, eu descomentava a linha dele que estava no final do `array`, enquanto **Carrinho** estava no meio do `array`. Alterei para que **Carrinho** fique na mesma posição de **Carrinho2** e o problema foi resolvido.